# How to get last week, month ranks from one to many tables

Tags: mysql

I have tables that hold keywords and ranks.

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `hash` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `hash` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `project_hash` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `link` text NOT NULL,
 `exact` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `last_checked` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `keyword_rank` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `keyword_hash` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=206 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now I add one row in keyword_rank each day. And I get its latest rank like this.

```
SELECT k.keyword, k.link, kr.rank as rank
FROM keywords k
    INNER JOIN keyword_rank kr on kr.keyword_hash=k.hash 
        AND kr.id = (SELECT id FROM keyword_rank 
                    WHERE keyword_hash = k.hash 
                    ORDER BY id DESC 
                    LIMIT 1)
WHERE project_hash=:project_hash
```

Now I want to select last week's and last month's ranks from keyword_rank table but I'm lost.

**Edit:**

```
SELECT k.keyword, k.link, GROUP_CONCAT(kr.rank) as today, GROUP_CONCAT(kr2.rank) as week, GROUP_CONCAT(kr3.rank) as month
FROM keywords k
LEFT JOIN keyword_rank kr on kr.keyword_hash=k.hash AND (date(kr.date) = CURDATE())
LEFT JOIN keyword_rank kr2 on kr2.keyword_hash=k.hash AND (date(kr2.date) =  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
LEFT JOIN keyword_rank kr3 on kr3.keyword_hash=k.hash AND (date(kr3.date) =  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY))
WHERE project_hash='6B86B2_NTU'
GROUP BY k.hash
```

[image]

Comment: Its always best to show us the REAL Schema for the relevant tables. try posting a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each of the tables

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I have added schema.

Comment: So it turns out you have date columns all over the place. Did you try amending the query to use any of them?

Comment: (See edit). Is this the correct way to use GROUP_CONCAT and Left Joins?